# How to let the DBMS inform me when anything have been changed?

Tags: database

I am planning to design a system which can monitor a database (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, anyhow). Once a change (insertion of new records, etc.) to the database have been made, a piece of information will be shown.

Is there a way to let the DBMS inform me when anything have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

`Triggers` is what you need to read about

http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-triggers.htm

One idea would be, you can have another table where the triggers will monitor the table and updates that table and your system can only `poll` that particular table.

[Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)

Also you can make triggers to send you email and you can `poll` the email server. Depends on how you design your monitoring system