# How to implement triggers when database changes in sql

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm developing Windows forms Application using Microsoft.Net, VB and Sql. Which is managing repository from databases of OLTP.

I want to implement triggering system, such that when data inserted in `OLTP's database` it will be notified to me so that I can update my own Application's data in order to get most recent data.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look into service broker...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use database mail and create SQL triggers on your corresponding Tables

refer this link

[Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)

Comment: Is there any other way for triggering that changes database, as I've to link the some other function to that trigger for the Loading of data in the Application Database

Comment: You could link your function and call the function from within this same trigger as well..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx). I'd caution you against hooking up a client application directly to it (as opposed to an intervening back-end service that your client talks to), but there you have it.

Comment: I got this, as i studied from the link provided above its for the cache applications and used with web applications..but i wan that for the windows application with Sql-Database

Comment: The backend client doesn't matter - you can use it in a windows app if you want to. I'm sure that the example given was just that - an example.