# SSRS subcription email with new entry

Tags: reporting-services

I hope someone can guide me or point me to a guide.
I have a report where it lists all the fees. It's very similar to the table; however, I would like for some users to get an email when a fee is edited.
I was hoping to use the "Subscriptions" option in SSRS but I'm not very familiar. Is there a way for it to send an email when a new entry is entered? or for it to look at the "LAST DATE EDITED" and when is today/now to send the new information?

```
ID       FEE NAME   FEE AMOUNT    EDITED BY          LAST DATE EDITED     
 1        MILK         5            JOHN         2019-3-15 13:59:22.110  
 2        WATER        3            JOSEPH       2019-3-12 16:55:30.710 
 3        SUGAR        8            DANIEL       2019-3-10 15:45:13.567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, the closest SSRS native functionality is a Data-Driven Subscription.

The subscription can be set on a daily basis

The dataset of the report is to get data of the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT [ID]
,      [FEE NAME]
,      [FEE AMOUNT]
,      [EDITED BY]
,      [LAST DATE EDITED]  
FROM yourTable
WHERE [LAST DATE EDITED] > GETDATE()-1
```

Data-driven subscription dataset will trigger email only if there is at least a single row changed within the searched time range

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'someone@examle.com' as email 
FROM yourTable
WHERE [LAST DATE EDITED] > GETDATE()-1
```

Worth to mention, that such type of subscription available in the Enterprise edition only

---

If SSRS usage in not a requirement, a similar solution can be achieved using a combination of the update trigger and the "database mail".

Nice example: [Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)

Comment: Thank you for the clear response Alexander. Yeah, I'm also investigating about triggers. That might be the right path because I would like to keep information about the old value and new value and I think I might be able to do it with a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Report Server and select Subscriptions. Then choose the type to "Data-driven subscription".

The schedule should be report specific schedule.

You can add a parameter ExecutionDateTime and to choose it in Report Parameters under Subscription page.

Comment: Thank you for your response.