# SSIS package Mail Alert

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm

I have a date column in my table, an SSIS package that sends a warning email must be executed as soon as a date is equal the current date.

The problem is that I don't know what procedure to follow to set up a SSIS package that runs, checks the database and sends an alert email every time it finds a date that is equals to the current date

I'm a beginner in SSIS.

Comment: What is your question here, you haven't asked one.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know what procedure to follow to set up a SSIS package that runs, checks the database and sends an alert email every time it finds a date that = the current date

Comment: Why do this in SSIS, when it seems an Agent task with an `EXISTS` query and `sp_send_dbmail` would be more suited?

Comment: Are you dealing with timestamps at all in this or just the date portion?

Comment: just the date portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you do not need an SSIS package. You can do it with a trigger.
[Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)

In this way it is executed at the time of creation of the record and you do not need to execute the package every x time

Comment: I don't recommend sending an email from a trigger. A trigger should be as lightweight as possible.  Plus the fact that if the email fails, so too will the insert.