# How to create a trigger to send email when a new record is added in to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run an  interface with name 'personimport' it will generate a new record in the table (run history).

There are 5 columns in the table:

```
interface-id, interface name, date, personid, error msg
```

Inserting "1, qwerty, 2019-09-11, a1" is successful, but inserting "2, person import, 2019-09-12, a2" throws an error .

Whenever a new record is added into this table with the name 'person import' I want to send an email to set of employees.

How to write a trigger for this in SQL Server?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a trigger? Or send `dbmail`? Or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)

Comment: I want a create  a trigger on the table when new record added into the table and send an email saying that "new record is added into the table"

Answer (score 1):

You need to have database mail configured:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-2017

You need to create a trigger:

1. From SSMS goto the table and expand
2. Right click triggers, and "New Trigger"
3. Name your trigger, on table name, and after insert

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER SendTheEmails
      ON  runhistory
      AFTER insert
   AS 
   BEGIN
       -- Insert statements for trigger here
   END
   GO
   ```

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

   Then for the SQL to email:

   ```
   Declare @message varchar(max)
   Declare @subjectline varchar(60)
   set @subjectline = 'Your Subject'
   set @message = 'Your Message body'

   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    @profile_name   =   'dbmailProfileName'
   ,                               @recipients     =   'youremails@yourdomain'
   ,                               @subject        =   @subjectline
   ,                               @body_format    =   'html'
   ,                               @body           =   @message
   ```

Obviously you can declare other variables, and use the insert table for further information.

Yeah, and as Fillburt said, this seems like a duplicate of [Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)