# How can I write a stored procedure to send an email on record insert and flag as email sent?

Tags: sql, email, triggers

I have a trigger on a table writing to a custom table.  I would like an email sent when a record is added to this table.  I believe there will also need to be an EmailSent flag added to the custom table to ensure records are only sent the once.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If SQL server, then consider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a database mail first, then add a trigger for sending an email include new record and update EmailSent flag. Here is an example for SQL server: [Send e-mail from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)