# send mail after insertion in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called regis_tbl and in the table I have a field called 
Email. What I want to do is I want send an email to the user immediately the user
Inserts to the table. Please how do I do that

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set up database mail - if you haven't done so, this question might help:

[Scripting setup of database mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521456/scripting-setup-of-database-mail)

Then you need a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.whatever
```

ON dbo.wherever
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE speed > 100)
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'whoever@yourcompany.com', 
      @profile_name = 'default',
      @subject = 'Someone was speeding', 
      @body = 'Yep, they sure were.';
END
```

END
GO

Now, you're probably going to say you want data from the insert to be actually be included in the e-mail. And your first inclination is going to be to declare some local variables and assign them from inserted - this doesn't work because your trigger could be responding to a multi-row insert. So the right way to do this is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.whatever
```

ON dbo.wherever
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @body += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(some_col) FROM inserted;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE speed > 100)
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'whoever@yourcompany.com', 
      @profile_name = 'default',
      @subject = 'At least one person was speeding', 
      @body = @body;
END
```

END
GO

hat all said, I am not a big fan of sending e-mail from a trigger. Even though database mail uses service broker and so is asynchronous, I would be much more inclined to populate a queue table, and have a background thread that comes around and sends all of the appropriate e-mails. The twothree nice things about this are:

```
you minimize the potential delays in committing the outer transaction that fired the trigger - the more complicated your logic in the trigger, the slower you make that process.
since it is probably not essential that the e-mail is sent the microsecond the row is inserted, you can easily fluctuate the timing of the background process - this avoids having to check the table very minute, all day, when very few times it will ever have to actually do anything.
```

1. you minimize the potential delays in committing the outer transaction that fired the trigger - the more complicated your logic in the trigger, the slower you make that process.
   since it is probably not essential that the e-mail is sent the microsecond the row is inserted, you can easily fluctuate the timing of the background process - this avoids having to check the table very minute, all day, when very few times it will ever have to actually do anything.
   As @goodeye pointed out, keeping this process separate can prevent errors in the e-mail part of the process from interfering with the original DML (in their case, an invalid parameter to sp_send_dbmail - which I inadvertently suggested - prevented the insert).

Comment: From your answer I see a column name 'speed'. Should I include a column in my table called speed?

Comment: No you don't need it pls, it's just an example

Comment: when i execute the trigger it tell me Incorrect syntax near 'END'.