# Create Trigger on SQL table to email

Tags: sql, email, triggers

I have an existing table and every time anyone adds a record to the table where DBA IS NOT NULL and Comments NOT LIKE 'ABC%' OR Comments = '' then email me so I will know the new record has been added.

I've seen examples where the trigger adds additional information when a record is added but not where it sends an email.

Can someone provide examples, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger

Comment: 1) What DB platform are you using?  2) What have you tried?  3) You shouldn't use a DB server to send email.  4) See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387483/how-to-send-email-from-mysql-5-1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521456/scripting-setup-of-database-mail